# incorrect return output in def()

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, while-loop

I'm supposed to:

"Write a function `search(words, start_chs)` that returns a list of all words in the list words whose first letter is in the list `start_chs`.

If either words or `start_chs` is empty, return an empty list.

Since the returned list can have many words in it, the words should be arranged in the order that they originally appeared in."

e.g.

```
words = ['green', 'grasses', 'frolicking', 'cats', '', 'kittens', 'playful']
start_chs = ['a', 'c', 'g']

new_words = search(words, start_chs)    # ['green', 'grasses', 'cats']
```

My code thus far is below, however, it doesn't return all the correct outputs, only some of them.

```
def search(words, start_chs):
    k=0
    p=[]

    if (len(words)== 0) or (len(start_chs)== 0):
        return ([])
    while k < len(start_chs):
        if start_chs[k][0] == words[k][0]:
            p.append(words[k])
        k+=1
    return(p)
```

Comment: Looks like you  are only checking one word per letter.

Comment: You are using the same index `k` for both the start characters and the words. This means that you are comparing the first start character `a` only with the first word `green`, `c` only with `grasses`, and `g` only with `frolicking`.

Comment: You need to iterate through ``words`` and ``start_chs`` separately. Currently, ``k`` is used for both. Note that you can iterate using a ``for`` loop, e.g. ``for word in words: for ch in starts_chs:``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
def search(words, start_chs):
    res = []
    for word in words:
        if word!='' and word[0] in start_chs:
            res.append(word)
    return res

search(words, start_chs)
```

output:

```
['green', 'grasses', 'cats']
```

Answer (score 1):

It should looks like that. It's bad practice to use iterate list with index, use `for element in list` instead.
About your code, why it's not working. It's because you should iterate over whole list. In this example you only check if `'a'` equal first letter in `'green'`, `'c'` in `'grasses'` and `'g'` in `'frolicking'`.

```
words = ['green', 'grasses', 'frolicking', 'cats', '', 'kittens', 'playful']
start_chs = ['a', 'c', 'g']

def search(words, start_chs):
    result = []

    if len(words)== 0 or len(start_chs)== 0:
        return []
    for word in words:
        if word and word[0] in start_chs:
            result.append(word)
    return result

print(search(words, start_chs))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code that you wrote is that you are only checking with the character at the corresponding index of the word. So you can use `in` in place of this.

```py
def search(words, start_chs): 
   k=0 
   p=[] 
   if (len(words)== 0) or (len(start_chs)== 0): 
       return [] 
   for i in words: 
       if  i[0] in start_chs: 
           p.append(i) 
       k+=1 
   return p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def search(words, start_chs):
    start_chs = tuple(start_chs)
    return [word for word in words if word.startswith(start_chs)]

words = ['green', 'grasses', 'frolicking', 'cats', '', 'kittens', 'playful']
start_chs = ['a', 'c', 'g']

new_words = search(words, start_chs)
#['green', 'grasses', 'cats']
```